# AngularJS UI-Router, A state view for all url expect one?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible with ui-router (plugin for AngularJS), to have a state (and his template) for all url expect one or two ?

Thx guys !

Comment: One or two what? Two separate templates? URLs? Could you show some code that demonstrates what you're trying to do?

Comment: Imagine you have a graph view ! You want this view on all your pages expect on the pages with an url beggining by "admin/" for example. Do you see ?

Answer (score 1):

If there are things you show in the normal, user-accessible area of your app, but not in the "admin" section, I would organize it such that you have two "base" views, like so:

```
$stateProvider.state("app", {
  abstract: true,
  views: {
    "graph@": { /* view config */ }
  }
}).state("admin", {
  abstract: true
});
```

Then, all of your other states will inherit from one or the other (i.e. `"app.foo"` or `"admin.foo"`). As long as you have a `<ui-view name="graph"></ui-view>` in the root of your base template, it will populate with content in your "app" states, but not your "admin" states. Hope that makes sense.